# Which test was used to compare counts from independent samples in this study?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution

I have recently read [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7258755/) study on stroke patients and cannot wrap my head around which test was used.

They have compared counts at two different times (March 2019 and March 2020) and provided p values next to the counts, for example monthly and daily EMS calls, and stroke calls.

Was the Poisson's test used in this scenario? Is there another test that is appropriate here?

Comment: In its statistical analysis section, the linked paper says, "Continuous variables were reported as mean and SD or as median and interquartile range and were compared with the Student t or Mann-Whitney tests. Categorical variables were reported as proportions and compared with the χ2 and Fisher exact test. The analysis was performed using SPSS Version 25.0, and the level of significance was established at a 0.05 level (2-sided)." This is just fine until we see that no hypotheses are stated and no directly relevant data is provided.

Comment: Unfortunately (and perhaps understandably), many papers on Covid-19 have been rushed into print in various journals without full and competent review. Some have already been retracted and one can anticipate even more retractions as time passes. // There are web sites specifically for tentative, preliminary and unreviewed work, respected journals should aspire to maintaining high standards of pre-publication review.

Comment: p<0.0001 for the counts could not be the result of either the t-test or the Mann-Whitney U test. That's what I fail to understand. If there is a test that is applicable in this situation, I would like to learn more. If those p values are there because the paper was rushed, I am disappointed.